# What does script's own domain mean? The domain the script was served from, or its HTML page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

Does this mean that I can do AJAX calls only on the domain that serves the HTML page where the script is placed, or just on the domain where the script file comes from?

If my script is on foo.com, and it is in a page from bar.com, to where am I allowed to make a AJAX call? foo.com or bar.com?

Comment: Look at this post: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Social_Javascript_%28cross-site_ajax%29

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter where you download script from, it goes by the page domain, so in your case it's bar.com.

Comment: I think it’s the opposite way round actually. That’s why [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) can work.

Comment: @Paul - it's exactly as stated, not the way around. You can link a script from any source (think google cdn) to your page, and you can make ajax calls to your page's domain, not to the cdn's domain.

Comment: @David @Andrey: oh, of course, sorry — things had clearly fallen apart in my brain.

Answer (score 0):

Andrey's answer is correct.  That is how I do my exercise when I read Dojo book.  I always has
   script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.3/dojo/dojo.xd.js"

```
 in my script.
```

And I can make ajax call such as retrieve files from my own local c drive.

Answer (score -1):

Exactly, you can only do ajax calls to the domain your javascript file was download from. If it was downloaded from foo.com you can only make ajax calls to *.foo.com.

This prevents cross-domain scripting (security risk).

Comment: No, that's backwards. The page the JS runs in determines the origin, not the source of the JavaScript. Otherwise anyone could `src` a third party JS and use functions in it to access content on the third party domain.

Comment: it's wrong - you can only make ajax calls to the domain where the page is hosted. Think about google cdn, which is hosting jQuery library. If what you are saying was true, you couldn't use jQuery to make ajax calls to your server.